# Using a local computer as a http proxy

Tags: networking, proxy

I have two computers (both with windows) in my private network at home. One computer (A) can access a remote network by using a proxy (ZScaler) but is otherwise rather slow and I don't have any administrator privileges on this computer. The only purpose of this computer is to access a REST API (only available from the remote network).

I would like to use my other computer (B), to be also able to reach this remote network in order to work with the REST API.

Currently, I program currently on computer B, push milestones to a git, pull them on computer A and check if everything is working correctly. I would like to shorten this process by using computer A as a http tunnel? (I am not sure if this is the right word).

How can I achieve this?

On a random note: Both computers have TeamViewer installed and are connected to my local WLAN. I could get administrator rights for pc A, but I would like to not mess around with this system too much.

Comment: is ZScaler really a proxy or some kind of VPN? remote networks are usually accessed with VPNs

Comment: To achieve what you want you would need Administrator rights on that first computer, which you don't have, you could in theory just connect the second computer to the VPN if that is allowed by your organization.

Comment: @golimar, right. Might be a VPN. I am very bad when it comes to network related stuff.

Comment: @Ramhound, I could get administrator rights temporarily.

Comment: If it's a VPN then computer A may get disconnected from your LAN when the VPN connects, for security reasons. If that's the case I think you won't be able to achieve that

Comment: @golimar, I am connected to the VPN and my local WLAN at the same time (just double checked it).

Comment: Then use some simple proxy (one that doesn't require installation like `ncat`). Run it on A pointing to the REST API and try to connect from B to A